# How to set attribute to a DOMDocumentFragment in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have a DOMDocumentFragment - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php that I will append as child to a DOMNode:

```
$fragment = $dom_output->createDocumentFragment();

$fragment->appendXML($myXML);

$cit_node->appendChild($fragment);
```

Everything works fine here, but I would like to add an attribute to the DOMDocumentFragment.

I can't find how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can not add an attribute to a Fragment. You can add an attribute to an Element. In your question you didn't say to which Element exactly you wanted to add the attribute so it was not possible to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished by doing this way:

```
$fragment = $dom_output->createDocumentFragment();

$fragment->appendXML($myXML);

$cit_node->appendChild($fragment);

// Find the fragment node   
$doiNode = $cit_node->getElementsByTagName('pub-id')->item(0);
// Set the attribute to the found node  
$doiNode->setAttribute('pub-id-type', 'doi');
```

As mentioned by @hakre, it is not possible to add an attribute to a frgment, but adding the attribute to the element solved my problem.

Comment: This does not add an attribute to the Fragment, it adds an attribute to an element within the Document, not within the Fragment. Just saying, I can imagine your answer solves your original problem but it's technically not what you were asking for.